# Wordpress errors refuse to hide

Tags: wordpress

Hi guys I have a big issue here.

I have been trying to hide some wordpress errors that popped up after I did a move to another server late last night. The errors were not showing on the previous server, however upon moving they all began to show.

I tried the following in the WP-CONFIG which did not work:

```
ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

You can view the website with the error at https://www.stlucianewsonline.com/male-in-custody-in-connection-with-double-homicide/

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ini_set('error_reporting', 0);` Would be a dirty workaround. It's most likely due to a php.ini setting on the server that you're not able to overwrite within the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the server settings that was blocking the change I was making in the local code. The hosters changed the display_errors to "Off" in a php.ini file he created for the server.